# Unique constraint on DB field does not appear to work with ORMlite 4.31

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

This is my Entitys field declaration

```
    @DatabaseField( canBeNull = false , unique = true )
private String name;
```

When I create two instances of my entity with both having the EXACT same name,  the SQLliteDatabase has no problem allowing me to add both.  And both are defo added to the database as I have gone through DDMS and checked.

Any other way I can force a Unique constraint?

Comment: Not an answer yet that will help you, but question: a) is the DB table created by ORMLite automatically or is it created by you manually? If manually, did you set a constraint in the DB?  b) fyi - are you bound to 4.31? Because 4.41 is already out. c) can you look into the generated DB and check whether a constraint has been added in there (if the DB has been automatically created)

Comment: Not bound to any version as have only started using this frame work today. The table and fields are created automatically by ORMlite

Comment: The syntax looks right. Can you post the created table structure and eventually your java bean class. Have you tried to use uniqueCombo=true instead of unique, just for testing (even though you only have one unique field)? Or alternative, try uniqueIndexName = "ixName" instead. Just some test approaches, as I can't see anything wrong with your code above.

Comment: btw: the ORMLite google group is at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ormlite-user and quite active, Gray (the ORMLite author) usually replies very fast on there, but he's usually also around here on SO.

Comment: Here is my pojo entity  @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;
 
    @DatabaseField( canBeNull = false , unique = true )
    private String name;
    @ForeignCollectionField
    private ForeignCollection<WishItem> items;

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

Well dropped 3 more hours on the problem but finally solved it.  I had upgraded to 4.41 but this did not make any difference.
Problem was I added the constraint after the database had been created and when I checked if the constraint existed as per Mathias Lin I could not see it.  I deleted the DB and recreated it.  Presto,  works fine.  School boy error really.

Mathias, I would accept your answer but can't as it was in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the ORMLite 4.41 version or above. I was having the same problem (with the 4.38 version). With the 4.41 version the unique constraint was mapped succesfully.

Comment: FYI: I don't see anything in the changelog file that was fixed between 4.38 and 4.41 around unique-ness:  http://ormlite.com/changelog.txt